# Easier way to generate regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have some requirement to generate regular expressions for the below where column names contains the below:

```
ACCT_ID; CUST_ID; LID; USER_ID; USER_NM; username; authnctn_*; sign0n;  maid_nm; maiden_name; LOGINID; LOGON_ID
```

Columns are case insensitive.

I am working on a labeler transformation in Informatica. This transformation will label the columns as some identifier ( login identifier in this case) if the column has any of the above values. Need to identify columns which are related to logins.

I looked for some online tool but couldn't find and building those manually is a hectic task.
Is there a easier way to do it?
Also, is it possible for me to combine all of them in a single expression?

Thanks.

Comment: Need more info.  What's the bigger issue you are trying to solve?  What tools are you using?  Update your original post please.

Comment: I am working on a labeler transformation in Informatica. This transformation will label the columns as some identifier ( login identifier in this case) if the column has any of the above values. Need to identify columns which are related to logins.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use RegExr to build custom expressions...

Maybe this will work for you:

```
/(ACCT_ID|CUST_ID|LID|USER_ID|USER_NM|username|authnctn_|sign0n|maid_nm|maiden_name|LOGINID|LOGON_ID)/g
```

https://regexr.com/591d7

Comment: Thanks Ryano! 
How can i make that a case insensitive search?

Comment: Also, let say the string I am searching for is "metacharacter" now in order to check for a mixed case, I would have to write something like [mM] [eE] [tT] ....upto the last character which is a hectic task. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Easy. Just use /gi instead of /g on the end.